# How to prevent / remove blank line in console when printing list with custom print method

Tags: r

I am trying to reproduce the tibble-way of printing, for an object of class foo (which is basically a list).

When printing each list element separately, there is no issue. But when I try to use a programmatic approach for each list element, it adds a blank line in the console, which I don't want. How do I prevent this from happening?

```r
foo_obj <- list(a = "hello", b = "world")
class(foo_obj) <- c("fooclass")

myfooter <- function(x, width) {
  footer <- paste0(cli::symbol$ellipsis, " ", x)
  pillar::style_subtle(paste("#", footer))
}
print.fooclass <- function(x, ...) {
    print(x$a)
    cat(myfooter("s\n\n", 40))
    
    print(x$b)
    cat(myfooter("s", 40))
}

## This is the desired output
foo_obj
#> [1] "hello"
#> # … s
#> 
#> [1] "world"
#> # … s

print.fooclass_ls <- function(x, ...) {
lapply(1:length(x), function(i){
 print(x[i])
 cat(myfooter("s\n", 40))
}
)
}
class(foo_obj) <- c("fooclass_ls")

## The empty lines after the print are NOT desired
foo_obj
#> $a
#> [1] "hello"
#> 
#> # … s
#> $b
#> [1] "world"
#> 
#> # … s
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: try using `[[i]]`

Comment: @user20650 this works! awesome. Would you care making this an answer?

Comment: please feel fee to self answer

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to user20650's great idea! - I will follow their suggestion and self-answer.

The list object prints with a line break - but if we print the sub-element `[[i]]`, there is no line break. In order to get the names printed, you still need to add the names as well!

```r
foo_obj <- list(a = "hello", b = "world")
class(foo_obj) <- c("fooclass")

myfooter <- function(x) {
  footer <- paste0(cli::symbol$ellipsis, " ", x)
  pillar::style_subtle(paste("#", footer))
}

print.fooclass <- function(x, ...) {
  lapply(1:length(x), function(i){
    cat(paste0("$", names(x)[i], "\n")) # for the names, which I want
    print(x[[i]])
    cat(myfooter("s\n\n"))
  }
  )
}

foo_obj
#> $a
#> [1] "hello"
#> # … s
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "world"
#> # … s
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>